# TYPO3 8.7 / Extbase "No Properties to be mapped"

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have an ordninary model called "Mail":

```
Namespace ...
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity;

class Mail extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;
    protected $company;

.../**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $company;

...
```

I want to use it in a Form:

```
<f:form action="post" object="{mail}">
    <f:form.textfield property="name"/>
    ...
</f:form>
```

First weird thing is, the html the viewhelper generates is:

```
<input name="tx_myext_offer[name]">
```

But in order to work it should be:

```
 <input name="tx_myext_offer[mail][name]">
```

So I try to write the html of the input field manualy with the name attribute like "tx_myext_offer[mail][name]".
When I now send the form to the controller I get an error:

```
#1297759968: Exception while property mapping at property path "": It is not allowed to map property "name". You need to use $propertyMappingConfiguration->allowProperties('name') to enable mapping of this property.
```

When I debug the PropertyMappingConfiguration Object of the request I see that the "propertiesNotToBeMapped" Attribute is empty. There should be the attributes of the Mail model.

Somehow extbase does not map it automatically this time. Seems like I missed something somewhere. How can I tell extbase to map the the properties of the Model automatically?

@ThomasLöffler

in the controller Action which calls the form there is nothing exciting happening:

public function showAction()
{

```
$this->view->assignMultiple(
    [
        'mail' => $this->objectManager->get(Mail::class)
    ]
);
```

}

Comment: Can you post the controller action that calls this form?

Comment: read this docs. may be this usefull for you. https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1297759968#.231297759968:_Exception_while_property_mapping_at_property_path_.22.22:It_is_not_allowed_to_map_property_.22badproperty.22._You_need_to_use_.24propertyMappingConfiguration-.3EallowProperties.28.27badproperty.27.29_to_enable_mapping_of_this_property.

Comment: @PravinVavadiya thank you, I know these "docs", they are linked with the error message. But none of cases apply to me here. I want to actually find out what went wrong, so that extbase does not do the property mapping automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first. You have missed the attribute `objectName="mail"` in your `<f:form />` tag.

When you add this attribute the hidden field `tx_myext_offer[__trustedProperties]` and a bunch of others will changes and then your automatic property mapping should work.

Comment: Thank you Lasse, that's  it!
I thought the "object" attribute should do the automatic mapping.

Comment: No problem. The `object` attribute is used to set a default value for all fields where you use the `property` attribute - like in a `editAction`.